# Unique number of dates for certain criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, index-match

In the below screenshot I would like to get column E as my output. I need the unique number of dates where campaign/Ad group budget (col D) = campaign name (col B)

I tried using the following query "query(A2:E9,"select A, count(A) where E=B group by A")" and iterating it using Apps Script for loop. However, that did not work.

Is there any other way to find this output?

[image]

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with `App Script`.... ? If not, it should be removed as a tag and in the title.  The Query function also isn't really necessary (though it could be used).

Comment: Saying that you have tried something but not showing that doesn't help to make the question clearer  (probable this type of content should be removed from the question). Also, whenever it's possible show the sheet structure using text / markdown rather than an image (for more details about this, please checkout the  the faq tag on [meta])

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as [**text table**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/)(NOT as IMAGE) to the question. Adding such [md tables](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0):

I think this formula will get you both the date and the count that are unique.

```
=unique(filter({A:A,E:E},B:B=D:D,B:B<>""))
```

[image]

You could then leverage an `index` function to get just on column. So this would give you just the count:

```
=Index(unique(filter({A:A,E:E},B:B=D:D,B:B<>"")),,2)
```

while this would get you the date

```
=Index(unique(filter({A:A,E:E},B:B=D:D,B:B<>"")),,1)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this formula @pgSystemTester. This works similar to the query function =QUERY(A2:E9, "select A,count(A) where D=B group by A") . But I want the "count"values to be repeated for every occurrence of the date as shown in the first screenshot

Comment: Well then you would just take out the Unique in my function...?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(A2:E9, "select A,count(A) where D=B group by A")
```